# Supporting different revisions of XML format with Python LXML

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, xml, lxml

I am writing a server side process in Python that takes XML in a directory and puts it into a database. The XML that is put in the directory is generated from forms that are filled out on remote laptops and sent via HTTP to the server. When we add fields to the form it adds tags to the XML which allows for situations where one XML file will have more or fewer tags than another. How can I make my server side script robust enough to handle these scenarios.

Comment: I don't seem to understand the question.  What's the problem to look for the element you expect and enter their values into your database in case they exist, and just do nothing if the elements do not exist?

Comment: I am asking how to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845943/how-to-convert-xml-data-in-to-sqlite-database/9879617#9879617

There is different ways you can apply the logic in the for loop depending on any patterns in the xml, but the idea is the same. This should then let you handle the query much more smoothly depending on which values exist.

Make sure you look at: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html there a lots of great tips with using lxml.

Answer (score 0):

A mini example may get you started:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

doc = parseString('<one><two>three</two></one>')
for twoElement in doc.getElementsByTagName('two'):
    print twoElement.firstChild.data
```

Maybe you should have a look at the minidom documentation or ask further questions here.  But with that `eggs.getElementsByTagName()` you can find all elements below the tree `eggs`.  Of course you can be more specific than searching in `doc`.